# How to optimize influxDB configuration for high sample frequency time series data

Tags: python, influxdb

In our project, we want to store ECG waveform time series data. The sampling frequency of ECG is 200Hz, which means for 24-hour data, the number of time points is over 11 millions!

Currently, when we query the influxDB for a 24-hour continuous data, time cost is around 20 seconds in python using [aioinflux](https://github.com/gusutabopb/aioinflux)(Official influx python cost 1 min). I tried to work with multiprocessing, but not much help which only down the query to around 17 seconds.

My question is how could we optimize the performance of influxDB. I mean which configuration should we change to improve the query time? Our hardware is 16GB memory with 256GB SSD.

Thank for the help.